Sun Position add on animation
I have a question about the sun position add on for a project I have. I made an animation for the sun so it looks like it's going from day to night based on the actual time and sun position from the real world. I placed keyframes from frames 1-240 to achieve that.
The thing is now I want to have a camera movement but without the sun light changing but rather have it set on a specific time of day through out the whole animation. Last time I tried to do something similar, I just deleted the keyframes. But when I animated the sun again the time shifted a bit (ex. frame 1 was 5.000, after it became 5.75).
I'm just wondering, is there a way to sort of "deactivate" the keyframes from the render so I wouldn't have to delete them? I wave searched everywhere and couldn't find anything.
Thanks.
